# HTML::Element -> Replace text node with new HTML::Element

Tags: html, perl

How to replace a text node with new `<p>test</p>` in HTML::Element?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Mak Killbers' own answer, ripped from his question to where it belongs:

---

=== Answering my own Question ===

```
    $ele->objectify_text();
    my @childNodes = $ele->content_list();
    for(my $j=0; $j < scalar(@childNodes); $j++) {
       my $childNode = $childNodes[$j];
       if (ref($childNode) && ($childNode->tag() eq '~text')) { #TEXTNODE
          my $newElement = HTML::Element->new('p');
          $newElement->push_content($childNode->attr('text'));
          $childNode->replace_with($newElement)->delete();
       }
    }
    $ele->deobjectify_text();
```